# Need to set sonar.binaries for Grails compilation, do not know location

Tags: grails, groovy, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using JaCoCo with Sonar and Grails. From what I read, I need to set the `sonar.binaries` property in the `sonar-project.properties` file in order for Sonar to properly process the JaCoCo file.

I do not know what the value of this should be for Groovy files of a Grails app. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use sonar gradle plugin this should be done automatically and you have no need for a `sonar-project.properties` https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube